# GitHub ReadMe.md Showing Some Images but not Others

Tags: github, markdown, readme

So I was working on a little personal project with lots of pretty graphs in Jupyter Notebook. I made a .ipynb markdown file to make the ReadMe, since I can actually view the rReadMe as it will appear in the .md file when I move it over to GitHub, and it all worked fine and dandy.

And then I transferred it all to GitHub, and for some reason, 5 of the 7 graphs are refusing to appear.

https://github.com/nmwhitehead/Healthcare-Costs

If you can't view the code in the Read Me.ipnyb file, you'll have to take me work that all of the images would input with the same format of `<img src='Graphs/Healthcare_Cost.png'/>`. Every time I search how to fix this problem, everything says it's gotta be a formatting thing, but `<img src='Graphs/50%_Predictor.png'/>` is the same format and it's not appearing and I am losing my mind here.

Answer (score 2):

Your files contain a `%` symbol in their name. This file name is simply copied in the URL link of the image.

However, in [URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), the percent symbol is special. You need to use [`%25` in place of `%`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Character_data). Doing so in the URL [fixes the link](https://github.com/nmwhitehead/Healthcare-Costs/blob/master/Graphs/Bottom_50%25.png).

Answer (score 1):

[`%` is a URL metacharacter and needs to be escaped](https://pretty-rfc.herokuapp.com/RFC3986#percent-encoding). It lets you represent any ASCII character by following with the hex representation of an ASCII character. You use it to represent metacharacters like a space `%20` or `/` as `%2f`  or `%` as `%25`.

`https://github.com/nmwhitehead/Healthcare-Costs/raw/master/Graphs/50%_Predictor.png` means... well `%_P` is nonsense. Though some servers might accept it as a literal `%_P`, Github is following the standard and does not. The URL has incorrect syntax so you're getting a 400 Bad Request.

The `%` needs to be encoded as `%25`. `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nmwhitehead/Healthcare-Costs/master/Graphs/50%25_Predictor.png`

It's probably best to avoid this gotcha and rename the files. `50pct_Predictor.png`, for example.